# IIS8.5 Windows authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, iis-8

I am trying to create a web application in my company and I want to get the username requesting the page to define what he/she can do. My environment is a Windows 2012 R2/IIS8.5. The server is in the corporative domain. What I have tried was to enable Windows Authentication and Disabling the anonymous authentication.
Here is the Web.config file with the set recommended.

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
     <authorization>
         <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
...
</system.web>
```

Here is the Authentication configuration sets

[image]

My problem is that when I do any of the things above I get the Error 404.

[image]

If I let the Anonymous Login enabled and the Windows Authentication disabled and remove the Web.config settings the application works.

I need some help to guide on this. I tried to find a tutorial explaining how to do that but I could not find something that explain it clearly. I am starting using IIS.

**EDIT1**

I have enable the detail error pages and what I am getting is the error 404.15 (URL too long). It seams that it happening when I disable Anonymous Authentication in my application. Does anyone have faced this problem?
Thanks

Comment: You did not enable detailed error page on remote machines. Anyway you have to dig further by checking the sub status, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0--iis-7-5--and-iis-8-0

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tip. I Enabled the detailed error page and the sub error is the 404.15. The URL generated is too long. I saw some post regarding this problem but I wasn't able to solve it yet. If you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.

Originally I was creating the web application with `.NET framework 4.5`. When I changed it to `4.0` the windows authentication worked fine and I was able to get the logged user using `User.Identity.Name`.